# C# COM events are not fired

Tags: c#, events, com

I am trying to fetch events from the TaiPan Realtime COM server. I am able to extract other data from there. Accessing keys is working correctly.

But when i try to fetch events, the function is not fired somehow. Hopefully this is a small mistake. For better readability i made a small test code, which is easyer to read for you. After adding those ids to the Stream the Visual Basic debugger is working and it show cpu activity for com_test.

So i gues events are there but i made mistake in eventhandling somehow.

Thanks for help.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TaiPanRTLib;

namespace com_test
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var handle = new handle();

            handle.start();

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }

    public class handle
    {

        public int counter;

        //  this is a list contains the internal numbers of the taipan Software
        public static List<int> numbercodes = new List<int>(new int[] { 78379670, 78379685, 78379692, 78379669, 78379729, 78379672, 78379674, 78379698, 78379682, 78379681, 78379704, 78379689, 78379694, 78379673, 78379697, 78379687, 78379702, 78379690, 78379668, 78379671, 78379715, 78379666, 78379706, 78379727, 78379679, 127289939, 78379677, 78379693, 78379676, 78379678, 78379680, 78379688, 78379726, 78379686, 78379696, 78379675, 78379667, 78379703, 78379691, 78379684, 78379700, 78379699, 78379705, 78379695, 78379701, 78379664, 78379716, 78379982, 78379665, 78379707, 78379728, 78379717, 78379719, 7837971 });

        void TPRTDataStream_Bezahlt(int SymbolNr, float Kurs, float Volume, DateTime Zeit)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("peng"); // never see this in window - so not fired?
            counter += 1;
        }

        public void start()
        {

            TaiPanRealtime TPRTObject = new TaiPanRealtime();                   //  connects to launches Application
            DataStream TPRTDataStream = (DataStream)TPRTObject.DataStream;      //  attach to the DataStream Object.

            foreach (int db_num in numbercodes)
            {
                TPRTDataStream.Add(db_num, 0);                                  //  This adds the internal dbnumber to the Stream
            }

            TPRTDataStream.Bezahlt+=new _IDataStreamEvents_BezahltEventHandler(TPRTDataStream_Bezahlt);

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(counter);     //  counter stays 0 all the time
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            };

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: have you stepped though the code yet?

Comment: Sorry for my unknowns, I need to google how to do so. The CPU seams peaking now and then. My guessing is that i handle the events wrong. My main code is much more than that. With the original code I extract masses of data out of that com server. But the events.....  Anyway I will google and try stepping through that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to post the solution TaiPan service found out. To handle the events correctly you need to set "Embed Interop Types" to false in the reference properties of visual basic. here is a screenshot:

[screenshot properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt4pX.png)

hope this helps others.